# $ git log --decorate --oneline --graph of a remote?

Tags: git

I commonly do `$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph` to see the history of all my local branches, but is it possible to do this to see the history of all the remote branches too?

Comment: Use `--all`. The command you show should only show the history of the currently checked-out branch (which will include anyo the branches that were merged *into* the current branch, though).

Comment: A combination of `--all` and `--remotes` is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments from @torek and @chepner, this is exactly what i was looking for

`$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --remotes`

Answer (score 1):

With a rather long bash trick, you can pull it off:

```
git branch -r | while read branch blah; do echo $branch; done | xargs git log --graph --oneline --decorate
```

Comment: Or just `git log <options> --remotes` :-)

Comment: What? @torek? He knows git much better than I do.... I have a hunch he is Junio Hamano himself.

Comment: Oh, @torek.... you are right (as usual). I tried --remote and didn't work. Was missing the plural. Thanks for the trick.

Comment: Hah, no, if I were, there would be several things different inside Git. There's some design decisions I don't like... (I can never remember the plurality of various options either, I had to check the man page for --remote vs --remotes.)